# I'm trying to make a code to display my emails important values for the last month

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Why does this fail and in debugger refer to Next? The code currently works and imports 30 emails before mismatch 13' error code is displayed. The debugger picks up the next as the issue. I can't understand why it works for the first 30 odd emails before failing. I've already referenced outlook 16.0 in the VBA.

```
Dim olA As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olF As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olM As Outlook.MailItem
Dim lrow As Long


Set olA = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olA.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Select the folder number here where the first one is 0
Set olF = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("BD")
lrow = 1
For Each olM In olF.Items
If olM.ReceivedTime = (Date - 30) Then

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
        .Cells(lrow, 1) = olM.SenderName
        .Cells(lrow, 2) = olM.SenderEmailAddress
        .Cells(lrow, 3) = olM.Subject
        .Cells(lrow, 4) = olM.ReceivedTime
        lrow = lrow + 1
    End With

Next

Set olM = Nothing
Set olF = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olA = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting an End If on the line between End With and Next.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have missed the closing `End If` statement in the loop:

```
For Each olM In olF.Items
  
  If olM.ReceivedTime = (Date - 30) Then

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
        .Cells(lrow, 1) = olM.SenderName
        .Cells(lrow, 2) = olM.SenderEmailAddress
        .Cells(lrow, 3) = olM.Subject
        .Cells(lrow, 4) = olM.ReceivedTime
        lrow = lrow + 1
    End With

  End If

Next
```

But looking at your code I have realized:

```
For Each olM In olF.Items
  If olM.ReceivedTime = (Date - 30) Then
```

That is really not a good idea to iterate over all items in the folder and check  whether the `ReceivedTime` corresponds to your conditions. Instead, I'd recommend using the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Second, instead of getting separate property values from an item I'd suggest using tables. The [Folder.GetTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.gettable) method obtains a `Table` object that contains items filtered by a filter. If `Filter` is a blank string or the `Filter` parameter is omitted, `GetTable` returns a `Table` with rows representing all the items in the `Folder`. `GetTable` returns a `Table` with the default column set for the folder type of the parent Folder. To modify the default column set, use the `Add`, `Remove`, or `RemoveAll` methods of the `Columns` collection object.

```
Sub DemoTable()  
    'Declarations  
    Dim Filter As String  
    Dim oRow As Outlook.Row  
    Dim oTable As Outlook.Table  
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder  
  
    'Get a Folder object for the Inbox  
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
  
    'Define Filter to obtain items last modified after May 1, 2021 
    Filter = "[LastModificationTime] > '5/1/2021'"  
    'Restrict with Filter  
    Set oTable = oFolder.GetTable(Filter)  
  
    'Enumerate the table using test for EndOfTable  
    Do Until (oTable.EndOfTable)  
        Set oRow = oTable.GetNextRow()  
        Debug.Print (oRow("Subject"))  
        Debug.Print (oRow("LastModificationTime"))  
    Loop  
End Sub
```

In that case you don't need to use `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
For Each olM In olF.Items
If olM.ReceivedTime = (Date - 30) Then

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
        .Cells(lrow, 1) = olM.SenderName
        .Cells(lrow, 2) = olM.SenderEmailAddress
        .Cells(lrow, 3) = olM.Subject
        .Cells(lrow, 4) = olM.ReceivedTime
        lrow = lrow + 1
    End With

End If ' You have forgotten to finish your IF-clause

Next
```

In order to know about this, you go to the menu "Debug", and you perform "Compile VBAProject". This will tell you that you have a `Next` without `For`, meaning that the compiler does not understand the insides of your`For`-loop, indicating that something's wrong there (like in this case, the fact that you forgot to close your `If`-clause).